# Intuitionistic logic unit type as truth

Tags: logic, constructive-mathematics, type-theory

I am trying to learn constructive logic.  Why can true be represent as a unit type while false is represented as the void type?

Comment: You should give more context on what you mean by "trying to learn constructive logic". Are looking at it from a proof-theoretic point-of-view, category theoretic, something else? How did the question arise and what do you intend to learn through the answer?

Comment: Maybe it is related to the "standard" logical representation of *True* and *False* as $1$ and $0$, that in set language are: $\{ \emptyset \}$ and $\emptyset$ respectively.

Answer (score 3):

The main reason is categorical. 
If you see logic through the category-theoretic lens, true is the terminal object, and false the initial object. In $Set$, the category whose objects are sets and arrows are maps, the initial object is the empty set, and the singleton is the terminal object.

In a simpler way, it relates to the notion of inhabited type (set) in constructive mathematics, where if a type is consistent you can construct a witness, while you can't build a proof of false (so false is empty).